# Is it possible to AddModelError for ModelStateDictionary with Reflections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reflection

I have a controller which I don't know at compile time. So I need to use reflections to add a modelError. Is that even possible? Or is there another way to do that?

Here is how I thought it might work (but it doesn't).

```
var modelProperty = controller.GetType().GetProperty("ModelState");
var addErrorMethod = typeof(ModelStateDictionary).GetMethod("AddModelError", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
addErrorMethod.Invoke(modelProperty, new object [] { "key", "message" });
```

The error i get: **Object does not match target type.**

Comment: _ "I have a controller which i doesn't know at compile time"_ - that means you've got a _bad program design_ right there. Why are you doing things this way? Why can't the `ModelStateDictionary` in `Controller.ModelState` be passed around as a parameter?

Comment: @Dai i try to write a single test for several methods. The methods use different controller, beside that they are the same.

Comment: That still doesn't mean you have to use Reflection at all here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: added

```
var modelValue = (ModelStateDictionary)modelProperty.GetValue(controller);
        
addErrorMethod.Invoke(modelValue, new object [] { "key", "message" });
```

In my first try **modelProperty** is only a RuntimePropertyInfo. I forgot to get the modelState instance from my controller.

Comment: ...why can't you just use [the `public` `ControllerBase.ModelState` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.modelstate?view=aspnetcore-7.0)? There's no reason why your `controller` variable (local? parameter?) should be up-cast to `Object` instead of `ControllerBase`.

Comment: @Dai: and how would i do that?

i have:
var controller = _mocker.CreateInstance(controllerType);
(where controllerType is the type parameter passed to the test method).
As the type is not defined at compile time, controller here is always an object.

Comment: `controllerType` is always going to represent a subclass of `ControllerBase` so you can safely do `ControllerBase c = (ControllerBase)mocker.CreateInstance(controllerType);`